# How to create a MasterStep / BaseStep if the my sub step files already extend a class?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, cucumber

How to create a MasterStep / BaseStep if the my sub step files already extend a class?

Example code for one of my steps files:

```
public class LoginSteps extends DriverFactory {

WebDriver driver = getDriver();

@Given("^User navigates to the \"([^\"]*)\" website$")
public void user_navigates_to_the_website(String url) throws Throwable {
    basePage.loadUrl(url);
}

@And("^User entered the \"([^\"]*)\" username$")
public void user_entered_the_username(String username) throws Throwable {
    loginPage.setUsername(username);
}

@And("^User entered the \"([^\"]*)\" password$")
public void user_entered_the_password(String password) throws Throwable {
    l
```

I need to use the following tags/ code below but i dont want to repeat within every step class / file and when trying to add the cucumber tags inside my DriverFactory im not allowed to because Cucumber dosnt allow you to add tags inside extended classes.

```
    @After
public void close_browser_window(Scenario scenario) throws Exception {
    if (scenario.isFailed()) {
        scenario.embed(((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES), "image/png");
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Think about why `LoginSteps` extends `DriverFactory`.  Is it really a type of `DriverFactory`?  Consider using composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: @azurefrog thanks but i need a location to initialise my other classes,   basePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, BasePage.class);

Comment: You do not need to repeat After hook code in all classes. Mention it in any class and cucumber will pick it up. For each scenario a new instance of all step definition and hook classes is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer:

Add hooks to a separate class which deals with all your before / after scenario setup and teardown -

```
public class Hooks {

private static WebDriver driver;

public static WebDriver getDriver() { 
  return driver;
}

@Before
public void startTest(Scenario scenario) {
    driver = new DriverFactory("chrome");
}

@After
public void close_browser_window(Scenario scenario) throws Exception {
 if (scenario.isFailed()) {
    scenario.embed(((TakesScreenshot)      
 driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES), "image/png");
 
 driver.close()
}
}

public class LoginSteps {

  WebDriver driver = Hooks.getDriver();
  //steps
}
```

For a more advanced way of doing things take a look at dependency injection with something like PicoContainer, so you don't have to rely on a static WebDriver instance within hooks and you can instead pass it into the constructor of each of your step classes.

Comment: You are not allowed to extend classes which contain step definitions or hooks

Comment: Fantastic glad i could help :) @Gbru

Comment: I dont understand. Why you created three levels instead of two?

Comment: @Čamo don't understand my own answer, which it would appear was wrong yet still accepted.  Updated to something a little more sensible.